# Running (& compiling) untrusted user code

Tags: linux, security, virtual-machine, sandbox

I want to create a application that contains a feature that allows users to submit code and the server will compile and run it, similar to Ideone & Spoj. How do I do this securely in a scalable manner?

Partial Solutions I'm aware of:

**IDEA 1 - 3rd Party Services**

The [Sphere Engine](http://sphere-engine.com/?utm_campaign=permanent&utm_medium=main&utm_source=ideone). However this costs a LOT of money!

I'm not aware of any open source application I can run on my server to achieve this, or a cheaper alternative. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

**IDEA 2 - VM**

This would be the next most sensible choice. However, I'm unsure how to implement it. For example let's say I created a VM and started to run the user's code. This would restrict damage on MY system, but not the damage on the VM, which other users would have to use. Does that mean I have to create a new VM each and every time I want to compile and run user's code (which clearly is not scalable - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Probably the best base would be to start with `docker`. Docker is similar to a VM, but it virtualizes a process, not an operating system. You can then use file system overlays to offer an interaction ("running of an application") whilst not risking persistent damage to your host system.

Comment: Another service I was aware of, but the issue with docker is that I heard it's not entirely secure to be used in this way.

Comment: It is difficult to discuss rumors. :-)

Comment: I am just basing this on the comments under here: http://blog.remoteinterview.io/post/89639823776/how-we-used-docker-to-compile-and-run-untrusted

Comment: I can't really extract any further information from that text as well, except some rumor again, more or less. The only real reference is in the first comment which again points to two documents, but they are pretty outdated. It really would make sense to check if the statements are still valid. Docker advances at a tremendous speed. I think you are more addressing a general issue here: you will never have a base where you can be absolutely sure that it is "secure". That is a general thing in computing, isn't it? So it applies to _all_ approaches you take into consideration.

Comment: True, but I'm just looking for the "best" scalable way of approaching this issue the way Ideone and others have done. But put it that way, "Docker" seems like a good alternative to VM's.

Answer (score 0):

Having not set up a thing, I assumed that services like TravisCI (which compiles code and runs it under test cases you provide), have a base virtual machine image, which boots up and processes your code. The next user to come along gets a separate VM booted from the same base image, your changes aren't stored.

So inside the VM, the user code can do whatever. All of its effects, except stuff written to the console will be erased at the end of the time limit.